# Create DataSource for DB2 Provider using wsadmin (Websphere Application Server 8.5)

Tags: db2, websphere, datasource, jython, wsadmin

I have a script which create a Data Source using a DB2 JDBC Provider in Websphere Application Server 8.5. So I am fighting with an error while running the script and I need some help pls.

**My script:**

```
def createDB2(list):
    print 'Creating DB2 Data Source...'
    for dataSource in list:
        datasourceName=dataSource[0]
        dsJNDIName=dataSource[1]
        compAuthAlias=dataSource[2]
        providerName=dataSource[3]
        dataStoreHelperClassName=dataSource[4]
        description=dataSource[5]
        serverName=dataSource[6]
        databaseMaxConnections=dataSource[7]
        databaseMinConnections=dataSource[8]
        databaseconnTimeout=dataSource[9]
        databasereapTime=dataSource[10]
        databaseunusedTimeout=dataSource[11]
        databaseagedTimeout=dataSource[12]

    #Creare sursa de date
    dataSourceId = AdminJDBC.createDataSourceAtScope( scope, providerName, datasourceName, dsJNDIName, dataStoreHelperClassName, serverName, [['componentManagedAuthenticationAlias',compAuthAlias],['containerManagedPersistence','true'],['description',description]] )

    connectionPoolList = AdminConfig.list('ConnectionPool', dataSourceId)
    connectionPoolList = AdminUtilities.convertToList(connectionPoolList)
    connectionPoolId = connectionPoolList[0]
    AdminConfig.modify(connectionPoolId, [["maxConnections", databaseMaxConnections], ["minConnections", databaseMinConnections], ["connectionTimeout", databaseconnTimeout], ["reapTime", databasereapTime], ["unusedTimeout", databaseunusedTimeout], ["agedTimeout", databaseagedTimeout]])

    print 'Saving configuration...'
    AdminConfig.save()
    print "Configuration saved."
```

**My input list:**

```
[datasourceName, JNDIName, AuthAlias, providerName, dataStoreHelperClassName, description, srvName,  maxConnections, minConnections, connTimeout, reapTime, unusedTimeout, agedTimeout]
```

I am using the same script to create an Oracle Data Source with no errors. The difference that I know between theese process is the serverName. For DB2 is a ServerName and for Oracle is an URL. Is there another difference that I don't know? Does anyone see an error or a mistake in my code?

**My error:**

```
Exception: com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: WASX8018E: Cannot find a match for option value [databaseName, java.lang.String, TestSRV] for step configureResourceProperties 
WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "createDataSource.py"; exception information: com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: WASX8018E: Cannot find a match for option value [databaseName, java.lang.String, TestSRV] for step configureResourceProperties
```

If you need more information leave a comment pls. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 03.03.2015**

I found some examples in a RedBook from IBM.

*Examples scripts for the DB2 database type:*

*The following example script includes optional attributes in a string format:*

```
AdminJDBC.createDataSourceAtScope("Cell=IBM-F4A849C57A0Cell01,Node=IBM-F4A849C57A0Node01,Server=server1", "MyTestJDBCProviderName", "newds2", "newds2/jndi", "com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.DB2UniversalDataStoreHelper", "db1", " category=myCategory, componentManagedAuthenticationAlias=CellManager01/AuthDataAliase, containerManagedPersistence=true, description=’My description’, xaRecoveryAuthAlias=CellManager01/xaAliase", "serverName=localhost, driverType=4,portNumber=50000")
```

*The following example script includes optional attributes in a list format:*

```
AdminJDBC.createDataSourceAtScope("Cell=IBM-F4A849C57A0Cell01,Node=IBM-F4A849C57A0Node01,Server=server1", "MyTestJDBCProviderName", "newds2", "newds2/jndi", "com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.DB2UniversalDataStoreHelper", "db1", [[’category’, ’myCategory’], [’componentManagedAuthenticationAlias’, ’CellManager01/AuthDataAliase’], [’containerManagedPersistence’, ’true’], [’description’, ’My description’], [’xaRecoveryAuthAlias’, ’CellManager01/xaAliase’]] , [[’serverName’, ’localhost’], [’driverType’, 4], [’portNumber’, 50000]])
```

**EDIT 16.04.2015**

I am using the built in function *createDataSourceAtScope* and I have another example:

```
def createDataSourceAtScope( scope, JDBCName, datasourceName, jndiName, dataStoreHelperClassName, dbName, otherAttrsList=[], resourceAttrsList=[],  failonerror=AdminUtilities._BLANK_ ):
```

I have to call the function like above. Did anyone see the problem? :)

The built-in scripts are in:`dmgrProfile/scriptLibraries/resources/JDBC/V70`

I still don't know how to fix my problem. If anyone has an ideea please leave a comment or an answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: Does anyone has an ideea how to solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Any ideeas? I don't have a fix. :( Thanks in advance!

Comment: Having same issue -  I am using createDataSourceAtScope of AdminJDBC. can you share how you resolved this?

Comment: Hi! I didn't solve the problem at that moment. I think I found some workaround. I can't remember. I will search those scripts and answer.

Comment: thanks. i also ended up extending the script and got it working. looks like problem with script as non-jt400 are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's too late, but I struggled with the same problem for Websphere on Docker. Then, I would like to share my solution.

#### Command to debug the scripts on `ibmcom/websphere-traditional:8.5.5.18`

`/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin/wsadmin.sh -conntype None -f exportConfig.py`

#### Jython script

```py
import os
import sys

newjdbc = AdminConfig.getid('/JDBCProvider:"DB2 Universal JDBC Driver Provider"/')

ds = AdminTask.createDatasource(newjdbc, '[-name NameDataSource -jndiName jdbc/NameDataSource -description "DB2 Universal Driver Datasource" -dataStoreHelperClassName com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.DB2UniversalDataStoreHelper -containerManagedPersistence true -componentManagedAuthenticationAlias db2inst1 -configureResourceProperties [[databaseName java.lang.String SAMPLE][portNumber java.lang.Integer 50000][serverName java.lang.String 172.17.0.3]]]')
AdminConfig.create('MappingModule', ds, '[[authDataAlias db2inst1] [mappingConfigAlias "DefaultPrincipalMapping"]]')


AdminConfig.save()
```